# Capture numbers and strings from comma separatated value file

Tags: regex

I have a file which contains strings that begins and end with double quotes. Each string can contain a comma. 
Numbers do not begin or end with double quotes. Each integer and string are separated by a comma.
It is also possible to have a null value.

I would like to make groups witch each string and number. I am trying to capture each group one at a time.

I have created this regex, it works for every case unless there is a comma in the string:

```
/(?:"?([^"]*)"?,){2}/U
```

If I remove the ungreedy operator, the regex works for every case except for null values.

Here is an example of the log file:

```
196778,"df,fdfsdf","4.4","ds-sdads231-33","mmh",1,,,,,,,023,1,"20150,62519535TY"
```

https://regex101.com/r/kO5wM4/3

Comment: It might help if you explain your purpose and show something that you already tried..

Comment: @aashima: Thanks, I added the purpose and another regex I tried. Thanks!

Comment: What is not working? What is your expected output?

Comment: @anubhava : It is not working when there is a comma between double quotes. This is the current output of my regex: df . But it should be: df,fdfsdf .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(?:(?:"([^"]*)"|([^,]*))(?:,|$)){2}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kO5wM4/5)

Comment: Your Regex does not work after the eighth match. Also {5}, {6} and {7} return mmh. They should respectively return mmh, 1 and nothing.

Comment: There is no real need to un-accept a previously working answer to ask a question in comments. Anyway check my updated answer and new demo.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I accepted it again. I added a ? near the end of the Regex because the last value in the log file was not working since it does not end with a comma. (?:(?:"([^"]*)"|([^,]*)),?){1}